# WebService call under Xamarin.Forms returning incomplete result

Tags: web-services, xamarin, task, .net-4.5, portable-class-library

`Namespace.References` is a PCL `Profile 78` project containing a reference to a webservice (`asmx`). Since the profile doesn't support the entire service model stack, only asynchronous methods are generated in the APM style.

When `GetLoggedInUser` is invoked from a traditional C# console project (referenced as a library) the service invocation completes successfully.

However, when executing the same service call from within a `Xamarin.Droid / Xamarin.Forms` project the service call completes successfully BUT the response is incomplete. The response only populates an `IsSuccessful` value found in the base response class.

See below

```
public partial class GetUserResponse : GatewayResponseBase {

    private User signedInUserField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public User SignedInUser {
        get {
            return this.signedInUserField;
        }
        set {
            this.signedInUserField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SignedInUser");
        }
    }
} 

public abstract partial class GatewayResponseBase : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private bool isSuccessfulField;

    private string messageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public bool IsSuccessful {
        get {
            return this.isSuccessfulField;
        }
        set {
            this.isSuccessfulField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsSuccessful");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string Message {
        get {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I invoke the service in the following manner

```
const string username = "user";
const string password = "pass";
var response = Task<GetUserResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(Service.BeginGetLoggedInUser,
                                                               Service.EndGetLoggedInUser,
                                                               username, password, null).Result;
```

Under a traditional console app the `response.SignedInUser` is populated correctly. Invoking the call whilst executing under the mobile platform `response.SignedInUser` is always `null`;

The service setup is as below

```
var service = new SoapClient();
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
service.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("https://address/Service.asmx");
var Service = (IService) service;
```

Invoking the service in the manner below produces the same result as the associated calls on each platform respectively (i.e. traditional console app vs. mobile platform).

```
service.GetServicesCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
   var value = args.Result;
};

service.GetServicesAsync(username, password);
```

Why would the service call fail in a manner such that only partial information is populated upon completion

Thanks